# How many paths of order $k$ are in the complete graph of order $n$ and the same question of a cycle of order $l$ in a complete graph of order $n$?

Tags: graph-theory

So I'm looking for a formula with proof, but can't find one anywhere.

How many copies of paths of order $k$ are in the complete graph of order $n$ and the same question of a cycle of order $l$ in a complete graph of order $n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the graph is complete, given any ordered list of $k$ distinct points $v_1, \ldots, v_k$ there exists a path between them. So we just need to count ordered lists. There are $n$ ways to choose the first point, $(n - 1)$ ways to choose the second, and so on. However we don't care about the direction we list the path in, so we over count by a factor of 2. Therefore the total number of paths of length $k$ is
$$ \#\text{paths of order $k$} = \frac{n \times (n - 1) \times \cdots \times (n - k + 1)}{2} = \frac{n!}{(n-k)!\times2} $$
Similarly for a cycle, any ordered list of $l$ points forms a cycle. However for a cycle, we don't care about direction or the start point. Therefore by counting ordered lists of vertices, we over count by a factor of $2 l$ ($l$ different choices for the start point, 2 choices for direction). So the number of cycles of length $l$ is given by
$$ \#\text{cycles of order $l$} = \frac{n \times (n - 1) \times \cdots \times (n - l + 1)}{2l} = \frac{n!}{(n-l)!\times 2l}$$

Comment: So this all makes logical sense. But say I set $n=5$ and $l=4$, I get 5/8. Yet the answer to a question on an old problem sheet is 15.

Comment: Ah, sorry, it should be $(n - l)!$ rather than $l!$, I'll correct the answer